# Javascript Injection Prevention (but keep text formatting and images)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

(*My apologies if this exists, but I have not seen a response to this flavor of preventing java script injections*)

Detail: All handling would be on server side.

I want my users to be able to post HTML tags in general, but I am looking for a way to limit what tags and effects can by used.  **Are there any existing solutions online for this?**  (I do not want to **encode** my users content.

**Yes:**

1. Text + Formatting
2. Links
3. Lists
4. Images

**No:**

1. CSS: by ref, by tag or inline
2. JS: by ref, by tag or inline
3. IFrames
4. Objects

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm considering the idea of wrapping the message in a basic XML tag, making sure it parses, and extracting a few specific tags (script, iframe, etc) and removing all attributes except known permissable like [a href] or [img src tag] --> and returning any errors back to the user (also helps guarantee proper formatting of html (open/close tags), etc.)

Comment: What is your server side language?

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19652/HTML-Tag-Stripper) is a custom module for C# similar to the PHP `strip_tags`. It takes a string and removes all tags except whitelisted ones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the HtmlAgilityPack to parse the input from the user as HTML and easily detect and remove unwanted tags.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: I've used this and thought about it, but I wanted to avoid it because of the extra processing requirements from its ability to handle improper HTML formats.  Other than that, it is still a valid solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I'm doing sanitization on the client side, I tend to reach for sanitize.js - I believe it has all of what you're looking for and more

https://github.com/gbirke/Sanitize.js/

Comment: I think the OP wants server side sanitation: _"All handling would be on server side."_...

Comment: No problem. That's a pretty sweet solution though. I'll have to mark that one down to look at it some more.

Comment: The reason I was looking at server-side was so content gets cleaned once and then trusted.  And I won't have to force the clients to keep reprocessing any fixes.  (also since I can't trust the input to be clean in the first place)

Comment: To be honest, I hadn't considered Sanitize prior to this.  I will look into this as well, but for now I'll leave the question stand as a server side solution.  - - Thanks :)